# An easy question with integer numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, divisibility

I have an easy question of arithmetic.

Let $a, b, N$ be integer numbers such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b,N) = 1$. Is it true that there exists an integer number $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\mathrm{gcd}(a+Nx,b) = 1$?

Although the question seems easy, I cannot find a proof. Is anyone helping me?

Comment: $b$ isn't needed.  If $(a,N)=1$, then $(a,N+a)=1$.

Comment: @Gaffney: $(a,b,N)=1$ does not imply $(a,N)=1$.

Comment: This doesn't look easy at all. Hm. Could be very interesting.

Comment: Asked before at least twice: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609810/show-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-integers-such-that-a-b-1-then-there-i and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647600/prove-if-gcda-b-c-1-then-there-exists-z-such-that-gcdazb-c-1. The first link isn't exactly the same question but the proofs given there can be used here too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classical consequence of the Chinese remainder theorem.
Denote by $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_r$ the prime divisors of $b$.

For each $i$, $p_i$ does not divide both $a$ and $N$.

I claim that there is a $x_i\in{\mathbb Z}$ such that $a+Nx_i$ is not
divisible by $p_i$.

Indeed, if $p_i$ divides $N$ then it does not divide $a$ by the
above so any $x_i$ will do. If, on the other hand, $p_i$ does not divide
$N$, then $N$ is invertible modulo $p_i$ and we have an $x_i$ such
that $a+Nx_i\equiv 1 \ ({\sf mod} \ p_i)$.

By the Chinese remainder theorem, there is an $x\in{\mathbb Z}$ such
that $x\equiv x_i  \ ({\sf mod} \ p_i)$ for every $i$. This $x$ will do.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ewan!

Comment: You’re welcome!